# static with generic types defined in superclass

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, static-methods

I'm trying to build a generics system that allows me to make subclasses that can call statics which exist on the abstract superclass that return the subclass' type. So far, this works:

```
public abstract class GenericsTest<T extends GenericsTest<T>> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected T createT() {
        try {
            Type supe = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
            Type t = ((ParameterizedType) supe).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            // This means that the type needs a default constructor.
            // Sadly there is no real way to enforce this in java.
            return (T) (Class.forName(t.toString()).newInstance());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static <T extends GenericsTest<T>> T fetch(int key) {
        GenericsTest<T> obj = new GenericsTest<T>() {};
        T ret = obj.createT();
        // do stuff here to actually fetch/fill the object
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Now, by defining the implementing class as

```
public class GenericsTestImpl extends GenericsTest<GenericsTestImpl>
```

I can call `GenericsTestImpl coolstuff = GenericsTestImpl.fetch(k);`, which is pretty cool.

However... when I add a second generic type parameter, changing the final type definition to `<T extends GenericsTest<T, E>, E>` the whole system fails, for some bizarre reason. The original superclass has no problems, but the actual call to fetch() says that the types don't match:

```
// Bound mismatch: The generic method fetch(int) of type GenericsTest<T,E>
// is not applicable for the arguments (int). The inferred type
// GenericsTestImpl&GenericsTest<GenericsTestImpl&GenericsTest<T,E>,Object>
// is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends GenericsTest<T,E>>
```

(added as commented code because the markup swallows <> stuff)

New code:

```
public abstract class GenericsTest<T extends GenericsTest<T, E>, E> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected T createT() {
        try {
            Type supe = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
            Type t = ((ParameterizedType) supe).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            // This means that the type needs a default constructor.
            // Sadly there is no real way to enforce this in java.
            return (T) (Class.forName(t.toString()).newInstance());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static <T extends GenericsTest<T, E>, E> T fetch(int key) {
        GenericsTest<T, E> obj = new GenericsTest<T, E>() {};
        T ret = obj.createT();
        // do stuff here to actually fetch/fill the object
        return ret;
    }
}
```

And the implementation:

```
public class GenericsTestImpl extends GenericsTest<GenericsTestImpl, String>
```

Does anyone have any idea why the additional type messes it up? As far as I can see, that does match.

Comment: That IS all relevant code. Create the `GenericsTest` and `GenericsTestImpl` classes as defined and it compiles. This is a test setup for now, with the final implementation meant for database object handling.

Comment: What java version is this?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt It's just the same with the `<T extends GenericsTest<T>` replaced by `<T extends GenericsTest<T, E>, E>`, as I said in the question. Do I really have to copy it all just for those 2 small changes?

Comment: please add all relevant code ( the new class with 2 type params) .  as i assume -> `public static <T extends GenericsTest<T>> T fetch(int key) ` changed

Comment: Yeh, I forgot about that. It's added now. The second type is not restricted though, so anything will do as second object type.

Comment: I've tried to run your code, and it compiles but fails at runtime when it tries to instantiate a `T`. Have you tried using `TypeToken` from Guava, which will make all this a lot easier?

Comment: @thecoop Do you mean the original, or the revised code? I hadn't tried running it yet; I was trying to get around the odd compile problem. The way to make the object was found here on SO somewhere, but you can always make it return null for testing purposes.

Comment: Both examples compile with java 8, but both fail at runtime as they try to instantiate a `T`. I would seriously recommend using `TypeToken` for this kind of thing, as it abstracts away all the parameterized type messiness for you - https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained#typetoken

Comment: That's not the issue the question is about, though. In that case, the `catch` will just make it return null anyway. I'll figure that out later.

Comment: Looks like the project's on Java 7... something that likely can't easily be changed (big project, multiple programmers, etc.) Changing to 8 indeed fixes it, though, so, thanks.

Comment: This approach is fragile anyways. What's wrong with `GenericsTestImpl coolstuff = GenericsTest.fetch(GenericsTestImpl.class, key);`? Would be perfectly robust.

Comment: @TagirValeev It's much nicer to have all functions on the actual implemented class, even if some of them are shared and can be put in the superclass instead.